# Clarifications regarding testing the cipher using NMAP scan

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, tls, openssl

I'm running the below Nmap command to test the strength of the cipher suites I have used in my host

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8673 <host>
```

My server supports TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2

I'm using an older NMAP version to test the cipher suite strength using the above command. when I checked the ssl-enum-ciphers.nse file it doesn't have  node which is available in [1] for the later versions, also ssl-enum-ciphers.nse file doesn't have any TLSv1.2 related configurations. My file is similar to the file in [2].

But when I'm running this command, I'm getting the below output

```
8673/tcp open  unknown
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
```

So I think the testing has been done for the TLSv1.2 as well. So how this actually works?

Appreciate if someone could explain, how this scan is performed for the TLSv1.2 ?

[1] https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.nse

[2] https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/luis/nping-ng/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.nse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<table key="TLSv1.2">`  is not configuration. The section you are referring in the NSE script explain the expected XML output.

`ssl-enum-ciphers.nse` script will enumerate through all [`tls.PROTOCOLS`](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/14f439a29ed873e4ec69bffff152e8d1ea463069/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.nse#L1134) and then enumerate through all [`tls.CIPHERS`](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/14f439a29ed873e4ec69bffff152e8d1ea463069/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.nse#L805) to do the required checks.

`tls.lua` defines the [supported protocols](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nselib/tls.lua#L24) and [supported ciphers](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nselib/tls.lua#L289).

My guess is that the NMap version you are using has `tls.lua` with TLSv1.2 included, but the `ssl-enum-ciphers.nse` is not updated with the TLSv1.2 related example outputs. It is anyway best to build latest version of NMap by using the source.